# how to search in specific field in solr 4.3.0

Tags: solr, nutch, solr4

In the previous version of Solr, we were able to search in specific field using this 
"fieldName:value"
Now, it is not working any more in the updated version of Solr (4.3.0)

Would you please help.

Thanks.

Schema:

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt" generateWordParts="1" preserveOriginal="1" generateNumberParts="0" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnNumerics='0' splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.HyphenatedWordsFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>

  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.HyphenatedWordsFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.ArabicNormalizationFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.ArabicStemFilterFactory"/> 
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
<fields>
<field name="Poet" type="text_general" stored="true" indexed="true" />
</fields>
```

I found that if I remove "solr.ArabicStemFilterFactory" from query analyzer, it works fine! so what is the link between them ?!

Comment: Make sure that the desired fieldName is indexed, if you want to see the value it should be stored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found that there is no problem in searching in a specific field in the new version, my problem was in filtering.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no change to this. You should be able to do fieldname:value. 
Check your schema.xml and make sure you have the field defined that you are looking for. 
Do a *:* search and look at the documents to see what you documents have to get an idea of your data, fields and their values.

Comment: Thank you, I can see the data in field by searching *, copying one of the terms and put it the query for searching give 0 result, I'm using arabic letters, is there any special encoding in solr admin that i have to use?

Comment: Did you reindex after moving to new version of Solr?

Comment: Please, can you post your schema.xml? the fields section and the typefield section (to understand how you are setting all the stuff)

Comment: @Hayaaziz are you using dismax or edismax to search? plaese, can you post also the query? Usually if you use dismax you should put the name field in "qf" param

Comment: Query1: select?q=Poet%3A"عنترة"&wt=xml&indent=true ,,,, Query2: select?q=Poet%3A"عنترة"&fq=Poet&wt=xml&indent=true ..... the same result :(